# What does the word "next" mean here?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

Please help me figure out the meaning of the word "next" in the following text (not available online):

*Along the way, you’ll see different space phenomena. You are required to gather pieces of stardust from nearby celestial bodies to reveal the **next**. Others are like the hands of a clock – you have to keep circling to wind them up until both are in line.*

I am not sure if the word "next" denotes "celestial bodies" or "pieces of stardust" here.

The text is from the description of the game "Little White Rocket". Here is a description of the game from a different source:

Little White Rocket is an inexpensive tappable toy, where each touch launches your craft along a path of stars, some of which aren't visible until you get close or complete a particular orbit.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: It means "... the next different space phenomenon".  It is somewhat awkwardly worded.

Comment: @stevekeiretsu Yes, that makes sense. Do you think the word "others" (first word of the next sentence) also mean "space phenomena"?

Comment: I think so, but it's not 100% clear to be honest.

Comment: Whoever wrote that paragraph should get another job.

Answer (score 2):

This is really ambiguous because, as folks have mentioned, it's actually very badly written.

"next" here could refer to "space phenomena", or it could refer to "pieces of stardust" or it could refer to "celestial bodies".  It's also unclear what "others" in the next sentence is supposed to refer to.

Based on the context you provided, my guess is that, most likely, what the author actually *meant* to refer to was "next stage of the game" or "next level" or some such, and that likewise "others" is supposed to refer to "other stages" or "other puzzles", etc, but they didn't actually state that anywhere (or if they did, it was before this, and probably too far separated to be clearly connected anymore).

But you're not the only one who would find this passage hard to follow...